# How to properly do an array of classes for a UICollectionView registration?

Tags: xcode, swift4

What I'm attempting to accomplish is this:

I have a bunch of classes, which define different feeds for my home controller. As I swipe left and right, it will show each feed from each class.

Now, I can register each class like this (which works):

```
collectionView?.register(VideoListView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: VideoListView().getCellId())
collectionView?.register(AlertListView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: AlertListView().getCellId())
```

Each ListView class inherits a base class called FeedView:

```
class FeedView: BaseCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

`BaseCell` just has my init and things I don't want to repeat in each class:

```
class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell
```

What's I'm trying to do is this:

```
let horizontalViews = [VideoListView, AlertListView]

for hv in horizontalViews{
    collectionView?.register(hv.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: hv.getCellId())
}
```

But, what I'm getting are these errors:

> Expected member name or constructor call after type name

and

> Instance member 'getCellId' cannot be used on type 'FeedView'

Okay, so I change the classes in the array to be like this:

```
let horizontalViews = [VideoListView(), AlertListView()]
```

But then I get this error:

> Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(FeedView,
>   forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String)'

That is with doing both `hv.self` and just `hv` in the `register()` call.

I'm new to Swift/Xcode development, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it with Swift classes (String, Int, etc...) and I failed.  But, with classes derived with `NSObject`, which include `UIViewController`s you can do it.

The common thing you want is `UIViewController`. So you can do like this:

```
var classes: [UIViewController.Type] = []
```

This means you can add anything of type "A type of UIViewController". From which, all UIViewController types derive.

You want to append something to this array. Try this:

```
classes.append(YourFirstViewController.self)
classes.append(YourSecondViewController.self)
```

Comment: Not sure if this really answers my question. Not unless I'm reading your answer incorrectly. None of my classes are inheriting UIViewController, they are UICollectionViewCell's. Also, I tried your suggestion, and received the error `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type '[Any]'`

Comment: If they are implementing UICollectionViewCell, you can replace UIViewController with UICollectionViewCell in the answer. Also where did the error you saw happen?

Comment: At: `let horizontalViews = [VideoListView.Type, AlertListView.Type] = []`

Comment: Durp, I see what you did.

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker Try to delete the last `= []`, try to use `.self` instead of `.Type`. It will be `let horizontalViews = [VideoListView.self, AlertListView.self]`

Comment: Ok, I was able to figure it out based on your comment. I had to change it to `.self` and then the register line is like this: `collectionView?.register(hv, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: hv.init().getCellId())`. The instance needed an `.init()` in order to invoke the function

Comment: You needed the `.init()` just to get the identifier?? You can also use `tuples`. Try this `let horizontalViews = [(VideoListView.self, "videoListView"), (AlertListView.self, "alertListView")]`,  then use this: `collectionView?.register(hv.0, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: hv.1)`

Comment: That works too. I was putting the identifier in the class for code separation. I like this better :)